# download .xls file in php(cpanel) using href

Tags: php, excel, download

I had .xls file in report folder

```
<a href="http://website.com/report/salesList.xls" download>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Download Report">  
</a>
```

was not working.

Instead:

```
<a href="http://website.com/images/123.png" download>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Download Image">
</a>
```

was working.

Need to give any permission for .xls format files?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions?

Comment: Permissions `0600` in cpanel.

Comment: For the .xls file?

Comment: What are the permissions for the image 123.png and the whole folder images?

Comment: @Nurzhan salesList.xls permission was `0600` in my cpanel. moreover it was dynamic file(autogenerated)

Comment: Have you tried to set it to 664 to check your own theory?

Comment: 123.png permissions is `0644`. it was uploaded file from local.

Comment: check apache or nginx configuration , or htaccess if xls extension isn't deny or something else

Comment: we cant change the permission because it was autogenerated when the page was loaded. if you change the permission in cpanel and refresh download was not worked .

Comment: i tried this rule in .htaccess, `AddType application/octet-stream .xls`

Comment: @Fky any other options to make downloadable that .xls file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the permission of `.xls` file, by `chmod($file,0644)` in php file where you are auto generating the excel file.